# Flexcel problem with open stream/file in .net core 5.0

Tags: .net, memorystream, flexcel

I have problem with open xlsx file in flexcel 7.6.4 (.NET Core 5.0).
I try open by XlsFile.Open() by memorystream or with fileName. I get an error: "Source array was not long enough. Check the source index, length, and the array's lower bounds. (Parameter 'sourceArray')"

Code:

```
void ConvertXlsFileToPdf(MemoryStream xlsFileStream){
_xlsFile = new XlsFile();
_xlsFile.Open(xlsFileStream);
using (FlexCelPdfExport pdf = new FlexCelPdfExport(_xlsFile, true))
{...
```

Any ideas? This same code work fine in .Net Framework 4.8